# Make flat appendix without chapters

Tags: sectioning, chapters, appendices

I am using the `report` document class together with `part`,`section` and `chapter` commands to structure my work. However, in the appendix this structure is too deeply nested, as I only have one Appendix.

So, what I want is:

- Only one appendix, with the headline beeing "Appendix"
- This Appendix being in the TOC on the same level as the chapters (Entry either "A Appendix" or "Appendix"
- Sections inside the Appendix to be numbered A.1, A.2 etc.

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\lipsum

\appendix
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum

\chapter{This should be Appendix}%This is just for showing, where it shows up, in my original, it says only Appendix here.
\section{First section}
\lipsum
\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

Which produces a nice entry in the TOC:
[image: TOC of the MWE]

but the first page of the Appendix looks like this:
[image: Image of the Output of the MWE]

So in this case the solution would be to remove the extra heading that says 'Appendix A' on the first appendix page. If this is not possible, any other solution to the problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the `subappendices` environment help? It's part of the `appendix` package -- no one forces you to use `\chapter`. `\renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}` and `\section` usage should solve the level and the numbering 'problem'

Comment: Not really. This defines the Appendix belonging to the section that comes before. I actually want it to be on the chapter level.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention that appendices  should appear on chapter level in ToC

Comment: @ChristianHupfer fair enough. I added this. MWE does that so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A version with usage of most of `appendix` package macros: `toc` and `page` option as well as redefining the `\appendixtocname` and `\thesection`.

Most times, it is better to use the `appendices` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\appendixname}

\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{\appendixname}

\noappendicestocpagenum
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\lipsum


\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}
\section{First section}
\lipsum
\section{Second section}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that the starred macro `\chapter*` does not put the extra heading on the first page of the chapter. Unfortunately, it also doesn't make an entry to the table of contents, and the numbering of sections after this is messed up.

So what you can do: Use `\chapter*`, repair the section numbering with `\refstepcounter{chapter}` (or alike) and make a manual toc entry with `\addcontentsline`. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\lipsum

\appendix
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum

\chapter*{Appendix}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\section{First section}
\lipsum
\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also a very nice solution. I prefer the accepted answer, because it uses the `appendices` environment. Nevertheless, this answer is equally good.